# Bluebird .map promise ends prematurely?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm running into a little trouble in my promise code where my Promise.map seems to end prematurely. I'm sure it's a problem with my logic but with the code I'm unsure how to debug it.

Currently, it outputs `[], B, A, A` with a `blobList` of size 2. How can I have it so that it finishes pushing to `imgList` and thus outputs `A, A, [*some base64 encoding here*], B` where in the `.then` function, imgList should not be empty?

**blobToBase64 Function**

```
blobToBase64(blob, cb) {
  var reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 

    reader.onloadend = function() {
        let base64data = reader.result;
        cb(base64data);
    }
}
```

**Main function**

```
Promise.map(blobList, function(blobObj){
    helper.blobToBase64(blobObj.data, (fn) => {
        imgList.push(fn);
        console.log('A');
    })
}).then(function(){
    console.log(imgList);
    console.log('B');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var promises = blobList.map((blobObj) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        helper.blobToBase64(blobObj.data, (fn) => {
            imgList.push(fn);
            console.log('A');
            return resolve();
        })
    })
})

Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(() => {
        console.log(imgList);
        console.log('B');
    })
```

Comment: Just to verify, is the variable promises an object holding multiple promise? And .all checks to see that all promise has resolved (or rejected)?

Comment: The variable promises is an array of promises. .all is a function that runs each promise in the array and only calls .then when all have been resolved

Comment: @Bryan, if `helper.blobToBase64()` is yours to modify, it's cleaner to promisify there and keep the higher level code simple. It's also cleaner to use `Promise.map()` as you attempted in the question, allowing `imgList` to be delivered down the promise chain; no messy outer var.

Comment: The helper function is mine to modify. I'll refactor when I finish, but this will temporarily do. Thanks for the recommendation @Roamer-1888 !